# Can Spring Boot application have separate security for REST APIs?

Tags: spring-security

We would like to apply Oauth2 based security for the Rest Controllers while the rest of the application will have Spring Security. Will that be possible? Can you provide any examples please?

It seems like WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter conflicting when both configured.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes it's possible**. Here the example template configuration code is given. Please change the required configs to your need. **The key is to define Sub static classes of configuration with different order.** Here i have considered any requests which is orginating from `\api` as a REST API call.

*I have not checked the code by compiling it.*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends OAuth2ServerConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            //Write the AuthenticationManagerBuilder codes for the OAuth
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                    .apply(new OAuth2ServerConfigurer())
                    .tokenStore(new InMemoryTokenStore())
                    .resourceId(applicationName);
            }
        }
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public static class FormWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            //Write the AuthenticationManagerBuilder codes for the Normal authentication
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable() //HTTP with Disable CSRF
                    .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and() //Login Form configuration for all others
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                        .and() //Logout Form configuration
                    .logout().permitAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to have static classes. The @Order annotation works even if you have them in separate files.

Comment: @HajderRabiee Yes it should definitely work. :) This is my style of coding. you can have your own.

Comment: @FarajFarook I take that back :) my application did not seem to pick up two different authentication providers when I had two separate classes (2 .java files). I'm currently having two static subclasses instead. Will dig into the issue later on, or if someone could confirm/deny the fact.

Comment: In my application, I have two separate classes and its working